# applet blocked due to security settings

Tags: java, security, firefox, applet

My web app uses an Applet during the login process. Everything was working fine until today when I was prompted to update from version 1.7.0.45 of the Java Firefox plugin to version 1.7.0.51.

I declined this invitation, but shortly after doing so, the login stopped working. If I open the Java console and try to call the Applet from Firebug I see the following messages:

```
security: LiveConnect (JavaScript) blocked due to security settings.
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.45
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
```

So it seems I'm trapped in some purgatory between the two versions. My is guess that either:

- the partial installation of 1.7.0.51 changed some security settings which are preventing me from calling the applet (from JavaScript)
- I can't call the applet because the old version is blocked and I have to upgrade to the newer version

If possible, I'd like to go back to version 1.7.0.45, and my previous security settings, because I know this configuration worked. If this is not possible, then I guess I'll try to upgrade to 1.7.0.51. I checked in the Java control panel for a way to upgrade, but there doesn't seem to be any "check for updates now" button. I'm using Firefox 26.0 on a Mac running OS 10.8.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to version 1.7.0.51 resolved this issue. I guess version 1.7.0.45 was blocked when this new version became available

Comment: You should have been able to revert to version 1.7.0.45. You can also configure your jar Manifest to ensure you aren't continuously asked to "update to latest". This security change was made in (I think 7u10 and the config was added in 7u40). These latest java security changes are a bit tiresome.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, applets have changed quite a bit as of update 51 (they are blocked by default). Recommended reading: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to revert to a previous version of java, see here for the full set of available downloads:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html
```

I had to do something similar for IE9 on windows due to the various java security changes between 7u10 and 7u40. I believe FireFox just uses the OS-configured java so it should be enough to reinstall the version of java you want.

As for the larger problem of applets in 7u51, I'm not sure of the best course of action (but am going to have to find out).

*Addendum*

1. I realise this doesn't provide a complete answer (i.e. how to reinstate your previous security config) but just finding the archived java downloads can be difficult.
2. It may be wise to remove/move your newer java install when retrograding (I experienced his issue with my IE setup).