# Java 7 update 51 - Prompts user confirmation message about Publisher name every time

Tags: java, java-web-start

Java 7 update 51 :  My application is java web start kind, in which we have addressed all the security measure in jar, JNLP files and signed the jar files with trusted authority , but Latest update is prompting user confirmation message about Publisher name every time. Message doesn't have any check box to ignore as provided with update 45 and further, so please clarify is this a normal behavior of this update or else any step required to overcome the same.

[image]

****SOLUTION:****

```
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

this attribute resolved the check box issue in my case

Comment: Could you please check what that 'More Information' link links to?  Maybe there is a more detailed warning or a FAQ where it explains something.  Have in mind Oracle is hardening security policies in client Java recently

Comment: Is the `Permissions` set in your MANIFEST?

Comment: It's probably also worth checking out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21145624/758831).

Comment: @assylias, `Permissions: all-permissions` is set in manifest

Comment: @Jorge_B , More Information also looks fine it has no any warning

Comment: @jerith2 according to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207037/java-web-start-security-dialogs-with-java-7-update-51), if you specify href attribute, checkbox will show up. Otherwise it will not. Maybe this is the case for you as well?

Comment: @eis , In my application jnlp file be created dynamically so i can't set that href property for dynamic file so plz suggest any alternative

Comment: It is a good idea to only request for those permissions you actually need, **not everything**. Also recent updates in Java have started asking the user to confirm whether the user wants to allow the applet to run. This is normal behavior.

Comment: @jerith2 I don't understand why can't you set it even if you create dynamically. Could you clarify that? even a dynamic file should have an url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Rob's manifest entries did not do it for us...  We still ended up without "Do not show this again..." check box showing under 1.7.0_51 for our app (when href= was **not** specified, properly signed, etc.).

But other of what Rob posted holds & that coupled with Andrew's suggestion of a full/proper manifest lead us to what worked for us.  From my post to [Java Web Start security dialogs with Java 7 update 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207037/java-web-start-security-dialogs-with-java-7-update-51):

Assure you've JAR manifest(s) such that no *Missing Blah-Blah-Blah manifest attribute* msgs show in console log.  The minimal additional manifest attributes for 7u51 we've found must be present (*s as test values):

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

Answer (score 3):

I have an applet with this dialog (after updating java to 7.51)... the checkbox is shown and works for me (dialog no more showing).

Don't know if this is related to localhost? 
Maybe check your security switch in java configuration (mine is at high).

[image]

**Edit:**

I think this affects the security/dialog-behavior: I sign my applet with an official CA-certificate and update the manifests of all loaded jars (using the maven-webstart-plugin):

```
<updateManifestEntries>
    <Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions>
    <Codebase>*</Codebase>
    <Caller-Allowable-Codebase>*</Caller-Allowable-Codebase>
    <Trusted-Library>true</Trusted-Library>
    <Application-Name>MyApplet</Application-Name>
</updateManifestEntries>
```

Finally in my JNLP I add

```
<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>
```

Comment: +1 for identifying the check-box.  If that does not appear, it indicates something is wrong with one of 1) the JNLP 2) the code signing 3) the JRE.  But you state it works in update 51, so that leaves the first two.

Comment: @Rob 1) can u plz confirm that your applet invoking with update 51 or previous update, u can check it in your applet java console, because update 45 and later had this check box. 2) tried all security level but the state remain same.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Even reinstalled the java but still the same, so Rob applet might be using old java update*

Comment: This is shown in the console, so version should be ok: Java-Plug-in 10.51.2.13,
JRE-Version verwenden 1.7.0_51-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

Comment: Maybe take a look at the manifests of you jars - I finally got rid of all dialogs by updating the manifests with the values stated above...

Comment: @Rob, every thing is already available as u quoted above, JNLP also got attributes u have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing a similar problem with my Web Start applications, but the post [Java Web Start security dialogs with Java 7 update 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207037/java-web-start-security-dialogs-with-java-7-update-51) prompted me to try to add this href attribute and it solved the problem. That is

Entry "before" :

```
<jnlp spec="1.6+" codebase="http://11.111.111.111:80/example.com">
```

Entry "after" does work:

```
<jnlp spec="1.6+" codebase="http://11.111.111.111:80/example.com" href="yyyy.jnlp">
```

where yyyy.jnlp is a self reference to the application jnlp file

Comment: as i stated above my application jnlp file will be dynamically generated for every user log-in and it will be unique, so it can't included in href prorperty since that file will not be available at any directory.