# Java Web Start shows "launched from downloaded JNLP file"

Tags: java, security, jar, manifest, java-web-start

I have a similar issue to [Java Web Start security dialogs with Java 7 update 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207037/java-web-start-security-dialogs-with-java-7-update-51)

and

[Java 7 update 51 - Prompts user confirmation message about Publisher name every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185322/java-7-update-51-prompts-user-confirmation-message-about-publisher-name-every)

My questions is Why are there multiple locations listed? Second location being "Launched from downloaded JNLP file".

I don't always see this, only sometimes, and I'm not sure what's special that makes "Launched from downloaded JNLP file" to show up as a location.

I know I can include the "Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase" attribute in my jar manifest to get the security prompt with the checkbox, but I don't understand why the "Location" section of the security prompt and how it's determined

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for that is because your jnlp probably includes a link to another jnlp. Am I right?

So the prompt that says "Launched from downloaded JNLP file" means the above location does not belong to the jar resources of the jnlp file that the user clicked, but it belongs to some jar resources of a 2nd jnlp that the original jnlp points to and was dynamically downloaded.